# How to estimate the difference between two Ito diffusions?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $b : \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$, $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^d \to
\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ are measurable functions and satisfy
$$
2\langle x-y, b(x)-b(y)\rangle + \|\sigma(x) - \sigma(y)\|^2 \le K|x -y|\rho(|x-y|),
\tag{1}
$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, where $\rho: [0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is some appropriate function. In addition, assume that the SDE
$$
d X(t) = b (X(t))dt + \sigma(X(t))dW(t)
$$
is well-posed in the strong sense.

We now consider the coupled process
\begin{align*}
d X(t) = b (X(t))dt + \sigma(X(t))dW(t), \\
d Y(t) = b (Y(t))dt + \sigma(Y(t))dW(t),
\end{align*}
where $W$ is a $d$-dimensional standard Brownian motion. Is it true that
\begin{align*}
&d |X(t) - Y(t)| \\
&\quad \le \rho(|X(t)- Y(t)|) dt + \left\langle \frac{X(t)-Y(t)}{|X(t)- Y(t)|}, (\sigma(X(t))-\sigma(Y(t)))dW(t)\right\rangle, \quad \forall t\ge 0? \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Using Ito's formula, we have
\begin{align*}
d|X(t)- Y(t)|^2
&= (2\langle X(t) - Y(t), b(X(t))- b(Y(t))\rangle \\
&\qquad + \|\sigma(X(t))- \sigma(Y(t))\|^2) dt \\
&\qquad + 2\langle X(t)-Y(t), (\sigma(X(t))-\sigma(Y(t)))dW(t)\rangle.
\end{align*}
Using $\text{(1)}$, and apply Ito's formula to the process $|X(t)- Y(t)|^2$ using the function $f(r) = r^{1/2}$, $r\ge 0$, we can **formally** derive $\text{(2)}$. But there is a problem, as $f$ is not differentiable at $0$. But I don't know how to rigorously prove or disprove $\text{(2)}$.

Thanks a lot for your help.